# Wordpress - Вывести контент страницы single.php

Tags: php, wordpress

При создании темы, используется плагин Custom Post Type UI.

Имеются разделы - `Customers` и `Projects`.

На странице `page-projects.php`, выводятся списком (ссылки) все `customers`, так:

```
<?php
  $args = array(
     'post_type' => 'customer'
   );
 $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
```

При клике на ссылку должен происходить переход на отдельную страницу с подробным описанием.

Контент подробного описания содержится в разделе `Projects`. Но на странице `single-projects.php` ничего не выводится, т.к. все описание находится в разделе `Customers`.

Как вывести пост с описанием проекта, который находится в другом разделе?

**UPD**

В шаблоне `single-customer.php` выводится контент из раздела `customers` (и это логично). Но необходимо вывести контент поста из раздела `projects`. Это возможно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделала так:

```
<?php if( have_rows('project-sections') ): ?>
    <?php $i = 0; ?>

    <?php while( have_rows('project-sections') ): the_row(); ?>

        <section class="<?php if ($i % 2 == 0) : ?>bg-gray<?php else: ?>bg-white<?php endif; ?>">
            <div class="container">
                <h2 class="page-head_sub-title"><?php the_sub_field('project-sections-title'); ?></h2>
                <?php the_sub_field('project-sections-description'); ?>
            </div>
        </section>

        <?php $i++; ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Нужно указывать

`<?php the_sub_field('name-sub-field'); ?>`

внутри

`<?php while( have_rows('name-field') ): the_row(); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Для этого нужен либо шаблон single-сustomer.php
либо стандартный если нету кастомного шаблона single.php

Иерархия шаблонов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]